# What is the fastest way to do database queries in a recursive function?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, sql-server-2008

A piece of my program queries a database to find all the children of a given elements, and all of their children, etc, until there are no more children and I get to the leaf elements.  The database uses two columns to store the information I want.  One column with the id of the element, another column with the id of the child element.  An average use case results in a tree with over 500 elements, and it takes over 30 seconds to finish all the queries.  Is there something I could do to optimize the queries and reduce the bottleneck on the server?

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
rootNode = Node(initialId)
nodeList.append(baseNode) # all nodes go into a list for debugging output
buildTree(baseNode, cursor)

def buildTree(self, node, cursor):
    query = "SELECT childId FROM Pairs WHERE parentId=?"
    cursor.execute(query, node.value)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for entry in results: # for each result returned, make a new node for each child
                          # and then query each child to see if it has children
        if entry[0] is not None:
            newNode = Node(entry[0], parent=node)
            nodeList.append(newNode)
            buildTree(newNode, cursor)
```

Node is short class that acts as a data structure to store a node's id, any children it might have, and the parent node.  I'm using `pyodbc` to connect to SQL Server '08.

Comment: Possibly related: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/transitive-closure

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks, that looks like it'll help.  I'm gonna play around with it and see how it does.

Comment: Did you consider a recursive SQL? Sql server 2008 R2 should already have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to separate your query logic somehow from your model (tree representation) This will allow you to be more flexible.

1) The first thing that coming in mind here is to use [recursive query in SQL server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to get all needed data at once,
but you need to be careful as SQL server has limit for recursive calls.

2) The second is to write stored procedure using first approach or the next one. This will reduce time by avoiding transfer and query parsing costs (but will defensively increase code support complicity)

3) The next is to minimize database queries number by selecting each level not each item. Like this:
 1. Select all root nodes
 2. Get all ids and query all child nodes using IN query
 3. Repeat from 2....

4) And finally if you have not really big number of records and they number will not grow significantly over the time you can just load all records in memory and then build your tree. You can think that this can slow down you code but without tens of thousandth of records its not.

Any case its really dependent of your data size and and other requirements, e.g option 3 will work good if your nesting level is not big otherwise it's will be the same as your code.

Comment: I used a recursive query.  It ran much faster and has cleaner code than if I did a mass select of all record.

Comment: Its depends on your situation as I mention in answer. Loading all data in memory is always last option if other is not possible. That's why this is the last option in my list ))